# Server SQL how to clean column using STUFF?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
608A
608 A
17113 R
16524 DC1
ASM-1780
234604A - Low L2 Cu
19658B-->
234605 - High L2 Cu
17015 Rev A 405734UD0A
43224A (W
23809 REVB
```

Is there an SQL server query that cleans the column above and removes the excess content on the right such that the data is converted to below:

```
608
608
17113
16524
ASM-1780
234604
19658
234605
17015
43224
23809
```

I have tried using `STUFF`, but it doesn't clean well.

Comment: Please explain the logic for identifying the "good" stuff.

Comment: please show us your `stuff` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want everything up to and including the first digit followed by a non-digit.

Well, this returns what you are asking for:

```
select str, left(str, patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', str + ' '))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bbf1d6647e2bdbd73986edfc1fe7cd2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: 0208-08-0031A --> 208 using this code. What if i want it to be retained as 0208-08-0031.   Apologies i missed out this type

Comment: @Tonz . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, I would advise you to accept this answer and ask a new question.