# SQL Server data cleaning of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
608A
608 A
0208-08-0031A
0208-08-0031R
1111-08-2222 DC1
ASM-1780
234604A - Low L2 Cu
19658B-->
234605 - High L2 Cu
17015 Rev A 405734UD0A
43224A (W
23809 REVB
```

Is there an SQL server query that cleans the column above and removes the excess content on the right such that the data is converted to below:

```
608
608
17113
16524
ASM-1780
234604
19658
234605
17015
43224
23809
```

The code below did not capture this -->

0208-08-0031A --> 208 using this code. What if I want it to be retained as 0208-08-0031.

```
select str, left(str, patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', str + ' '))
```

Comment: Looks an awful lot like a 1:1 **re-post** of your previous question, asked just 2 hours earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624980/server-sql-how-to-clean-column-using-stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually only a small tweak on that version:

```
select str, left(t.str, patindex('%[0-9][^-0-9]%', str + ' '))
from t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b59e04a0432d951859d16918dc2647f) is a db<>fiddle.